# Close multiple popup windows using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

The pop-up windows are used in order to allow the user to open a document pages in separate windows. When the user tries to open the next document pages, all the previous document pages windows must be closed.

So basically, I want to close multiple pop-up windows. In order to save the reference of the opened pop-up window, I have saved the array containing pop-up windows reference in a variable and the value of that variable is saved in a hidden field.

Now, `popup = window.open('', '', sOptions);` returns `[object]`, and when this `[object]` is retrieved, it generates an error that object doesn't support this property or method.

I'm using the following javascript in my web application developed using asp/vb.net:

```
    var popupWin = new Array();

    function OnPopupClick(url,title,name) {
        var popup = null;
        var sOptions;
        sOptions = 'status=yes,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,titlebar=yes,location=0,directories=0';
        sOptions = sOptions + ',width=' + (screen.availWidth - screen.availWidth / 2).toString();
        sOptions = sOptions + ',height=' + (screen.availHeight - 50).toString();
        sOptions = sOptions + ',screenX=0,screenY=0'
        sOptions = sOptions + ',left=' + ((screen.availWidth / 2) - 10).toString();
        sOptions = sOptions + ',top=0';
        html = '<html><head><title>'+ title + '</title></head><body style="margin: 0px 0; text-align:center; "><IMG src="' + url + '" BORDER=0 NAME=image height="' + (screen.availHeight - 50).toString() +'" width="' + ((screen.availWidth - screen.availWidth / 2)-20).toString() +'" onload="window.resizeTo((document.image.width-(document.image.width-(screen.availWidth - screen.availWidth / 2)))+10,((document.image.height*1.3)-(screen.availHeight - 50))+((screen.availHeight - 50)*3)";></body></html>';
        popup = window.open('', '', sOptions);
        popup.document.open();
        popup.document.write(html);
        popup.document.focus();
        popup.document.close();

        if(document.getElementById('<%= hidTitle.ClientID %>').value!=name){
            ClosePopupWin(document.getElementById('<%= hidWinRef.ClientID %>').value);
        }
        TrackPopupWinOpen(popup,name); 
   }

    function TrackPopupWinOpen(winName,title) {
        popupWin[popupWin.length] = winName;
        var index = popupWin.length-1;
        var val = popupWin.join();

        document.getElementById('<%= hidWinRef.ClientID %>').value=val;
        document.getElementById('<%= hidTitle.ClientID %>').value=title;
    }

    function ClosePopupWin(retVal) {
        popupWin[popupWin.length]=retVal.split();
        var openCount = popupWin.length;
        for (i = 0; i < openCount; i++) {
            popupWin[i].close();
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

I cant use any third part tools. I can only use controls available in asp.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a different approach. Pop-up windows pose all kinds of problems beyond what you're describing, mainly adblocker software. Even still, there is a much more efficient way to do this. Use either expanding or floating divs to manage these. Based on the Javascript you posted, none of the data is being retrieved asynchronously, so there is no need for a pop-up. If you simply use a function or .NET control to render the images in divs at the bottom of the page, you can use CSS and much lighter-weight Javascript to toggle those on and off using absolute (or fixed) positioning.